# How I can validate only some validation groups based on some fields in the form itself in Symfony2

Tags: validation, symfony

I have a big form organized in some validations groups. For every group in the form there is a corresponding checkbox which tell the server to save group data.

When the user post the form, I need to validate only validation groups whose correspond the checked checkboxes because some of their "sub" fields are required, but only if you activate the group. Otherwise the validator must ignore the required fields.

Actually I do that in my controller. I skip the Symfony's normal validation cycle and manually I validate every field checking for the group activation checkbox.

How I can move this validation logic inside the Form class or in a specific Constraint class used by the entity?

---

EDIT:

As said below is possibile in symfony 2.1, for now i solved:

```
$request = $this->get('request');

// myEntity knows the business logic to chose validation groups
$myEntity->collectValidationGroups($request);

$form = $this->createForm(new MyEntityType(), $myEntity);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Symfony 2.1 then you can set validation group based on submitted data. Check [this](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/forms.html#groups-based-on-submitted-data) section.

Comment: can't upgrade to 2.1, but it's exactly what i need

Comment: if you can't, you still can rely on request to gather the data bound to the form. Inject the request in your formType and use it to build the validation_groups option.

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibilty than the one offered by 2.1.
You can set the `validation_groups` attribute on the form using `$builder->getData()`:

```
// inside buildForm method of a form type:
$builder->setAttribute('validation_groups', $builder->getData()->getValidationGroups());
```

Comment: Sorry, but isn't the buildform function called before binding the form to data? Tipically I create the form and then bind() entity and then I call isValid(). Inside build form I haven't yet the checkboxes wich enables my validation group. Is it right?

Comment: indeed. Then I can't help more :s

Comment: np, only to check if I miss something ;)

Comment: The validation is doing when you binding data. isValid() method only returns the value, if it can helps you